# Error during calculation of age based on values in column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
-----------
60100412345
70111243335
```

And I try to create column "age" based on values in "col1" because:

- first two numbers is year
- next two values is month
- netxt two values is day

So, 60100412345 is year = 1960, month = 10, day = 04

And I use below code to calculate age:

```
today_date= pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=6, day=30)
df["AGE"] = (today_date - pd.to_datetime(df.col1.str[:6], format = '%y%m%d')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
df["AGE"] = df.AGE.astype("int")
```

but I have an error like: ValueError: `unconverted data remains: 28`

How can I repare this error ? Or maybe do you have another idea how to calculate age based on values in col1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time provide such snipets in order to help you faster instead of recreating your data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=['col1'],
        data = [['60100412345'],['70111243335']]
     )
```

The following function is based on: https://github.com/arthurdejong/python-stdnum/blob/master/stdnum/pl/pesel.py

```py
def get_birth_date(number):
    year = int(number[0:2])
    month = int(number[2:4])
    day = int(number[4:6])
    year += {
        0: 1900,
        1: 2000,
        2: 2100,
        3: 2200,
        4: 1800,
    }[month // 20]
    month = month % 20
    return pd.Timestamp(year, month, day)

        
today_date= pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=6, day=30)
df["AGE"] = (today_date - df.col1.apply(lambda x: get_birth_date(x))) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
df["AGE"] = df.AGE.astype("int")
df
col1    AGE
0   60100412345 60
1   70111243335 50
```

Comment: Mateusz, but what in case when at the begining is 00? or 01 and so on ? it is like PESEL in Poland, your solution in this case from 00 or 01 will make 1900 or 1901

Comment: what when I will have something like 01100412345 so year 2001, month 10 day 4 ?

Comment: So what do you expects from 20 at the beginning: 1920 or 2020?

Comment: It is PESEL and based on PESEL adn today date I want to calculate age of people. So only first 6 numbers is important but be aware that 00, 01 and so on it have to be 2000, 2001 and so on bu 99 and lower, 98, 97 and so on is 1999, 1998, 1997 and so on

Comment: If we consider taking age from PESEL it is not as simple as you write. Look at the polish government article on that: https://www.gov.pl/web/cyfryzacja/co-to-jest-numer-pesel-i-jak-sie-go-nadaje. Look at the changes in the code I've made.

Comment: Hmm I have erro like this: NameError: name 'InvalidComponent' is not defined

Comment: I forgot one line `month = month % 20`, please check the answer now, it should be ok.

Comment: Hmm I still have NameError: name 'InvalidComponent' is not defined

Comment: Yeah that part was unnecessary, please ignore it and try the code I posted right now.

Comment: One more error: ValueError: month must be in 1..12 hmm what do you think about it ?

Comment: Please provide me an example that is causing the error. What value is problematic?